# Python UDF for Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I don't seem to be able to find any example online. [Cassandra 3.0 supports UDF and UDA](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0/) that can be written in Java, Python or others.

How can I set-up a UDF or UDA defined in Python (I mean a Python function, not a function in Java or Javascript via the Python driver)?

Comment: The performance of writing a UDF or UDA in python will be absolutely terrible.  You should really just write it in Java, as painful as it is for me to say that (I'm a Python guy).

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear from you question if you want to define a UDF, UDA using something like the python driver, or you want a generalized way to define a UDF in in the language of python, but this may steer you in the right direction.

I found the following examples in the test_metadata.py of the python-driver here.

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/tests/integration/standard/test_metadata.py#L448

Example UDF in javascript

```
session.execute("""CREATE FUNCTION {0}.sum_int(key int, val int)
                            RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
                            RETURNS int
                            LANGUAGE javascript AS 'key + val';""".format(keyspace_name))
```

I believe you can toggle the language the function is actually written in by changing the language parameter above.

Here is an example of a function declaration in java.

```
session.execute("""CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_map(s map<int, int>, i int)
                               RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
                               RETURNS map<int, int>
                               LANGUAGE java AS 's.put(new Integer(i), new Integer(i)); return s;';""")
```

Example UDA

```
session.execute("""CREATE AGGREGATE {0}.sum_agg(int)
                             SFUNC sum_int
                             STYPE int
                             INITCOND 0"""
                             .format(self.keyspace_name))
```

There is also a blog post located here you can reference.
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-user-defined-functions-python-driver

Comment: Thanks. I clarified my question. Is there a `language python` or other language than `java` or `javascript`?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it out, but theoretically speaking you should be able to use any JSR223 language, which would include jython. I don't think python will work out of the box with cassandra. You would likely have to do something clever and add jython-engine.jar to your cassandra classpath. I'm basing all of this off of this article here. http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#jsr-223
I haven't tested this so I don't know if it would work for sure. If the function is trivial, the path of least resistance would likely be implement it in java/javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'm not particularly familiar with the Java "world", I'll have a look.